# Is there any way to read from specific EventHub Partition using EventProcessorHost

Tags: azure-service-fabric, azure-eventhub, service-fabric-stateless

I have a ServiceFabric Stateless service where I want to read from specific EventHub Partition using EventProcessorHost.
I would like to read from two event hub partition mapping each to one EventProcessorHost

First EventHub Partition => First EventProcessorHost 
Second EventHub Partition => Second EventProcessorHost

```
  var eventHubClient = EventHubClient.CreateFromConnectionString(serviceBusConnectionString, eventHubName);

            // Get the default Consumer Group
            eventProcessorHost = new EventProcessorHost(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                                                        eventHubClient.Path.ToLower(),                                                            
                                                        consumerGroupName.ToLower(),
                                                        serviceBusConnectionString,
                                                        storageAccountConnectionString)
            {
                PartitionManagerOptions = new PartitionManagerOptions
                {
                    AcquireInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), // Default is 10 seconds
                    RenewInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), // Default is 10 seconds
                    LeaseInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30) // Default value is 30 seconds
                }
            };

            ServiceEventSource.Current.Message(RegisteringEventProcessor);
            var eventProcessorOptions = new EventProcessorOptions
            {
                InvokeProcessorAfterReceiveTimeout = true,
                MaxBatchSize = 100,
                PrefetchCount = 100,
                ReceiveTimeOut = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
            };
            eventProcessorOptions.ExceptionReceived += EventProcessorOptions_ExceptionReceived;
            await eventProcessorHost.RegisterEventProcessorFactoryAsync(new EventProcessorFactory<EventProcessor>(deviceActorServiceUri),
                                                                        eventProcessorOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a github repo that has an implementation you can build from [here](https://github.com/khenidak/service-fabric-eventhub-listener).
It hasn't been maintained for quite some time, but it seems to solve your problem.

> 4- Single: maps a single event hub partition to a single service fabric partition.
>    Event Hub communication listener will expect a supplied valid event hub partition id

Comment: Thanks for response, in this solution it is using **"EventHubReceiver"**.
But I am looking something similar by using  **"IEventProcessor"**